# Regular Expression to extract only lower case letters in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string with a combination of both upper case and lower case letters but I need a string which has only lower case letters. 
Here is my string " mOTHER "

I tried the below code but didn't succeed.

```
 String testStr = "mOTHER";
 String regEx = "([A-Z])";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);
 System.out.printf(regEx);
```

Output :

```
([A-Z])
```

Expected:

m

What Am I missing ? Any help would be great !! Thanks.

Comment: `testStr = testStr.replaceAll("[^\\p{javaLowerCase}]", "");`.

Comment: You did not even try to remove anything, how could you succeed? You just printed the input string.

Comment: What's your `"mOTHER"` got to do with it? (No, I'm not making a playground joke, I'm asking about how this relates to the subsequent code)

Comment: Do you want to remove uppercase letters or replace them with lowercase letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  String testStr = "mOTHER";
  testStr = testStr.replaceAll("[A-Z]", "");
  System.out.println( testStr);
```

Comment: If using `[A-Z]+`, you could save steps.